# Ajax json requests and responses

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I'm hoping I can get some help understanding what's happening in this bit of code at a rather fundamental level.

I know that this is basically making a call to the specified URL. I also know that it should be returning a JSON object. If the call succeeds, then it calls my `displayResults` function, which I defined below.

The `displayResults` function takes a single parameter.

If I pass it a simple string for example ("response", in the code), everything works fine. However, I'd like to pass the response object from the API call as an argument to the function, but I cannot figure out how. Does the response object have a specific name I should be using?

```
$.ajax({
    url: wikiAPI,
    dataType: "json",
    success: displayResults //dont call the function, pass it. it will be called when the response is ready.
});

function displayResults(data){
  console.log(data);//here is your response
  $(".results").html("<p><h3>Hello World!</h3></p>");
}
```

Comment: and what parameter would you suggest? a random name?

Comment: any contextual name @JaromandaX.

Comment: really? and jQuery.ajax will "know what you mean"? `success: displayResults(anyContextualName)` ???

Comment: @codekaizer - you do realise the value for `success:` should be a **function** ... `displayResults("response")` is not a function, (unless `displayResults` returned a function, which it does not)

Comment: I've tried putting several different parameters in there. response, data, json_data, etc. If I pass anything that isn't a literal string or an integer value to displayResults, "Hello World" will not print.

Comment: @garroad_ran - ignore the uninformed comments, the answer below is correct

Comment: "you do realise the value for success: should be a function ... displayResults("response") is not a function, (unless displayResults returned a function, which it does not)"

Can you elaborate on this a little bit? My understanding is that displayResults IS a function. How is it not? I'm really trying to get a grip on what I'm doing here. I don't just care about making the code work.

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX, i may have dozed a lil bit. appreciated!

Comment: @r3wt You should never "fix" the code in an edit. That should be an answer, or at least a comment. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Comment: `displayResults` is a function .... `displayResults('whatever')` is calling a function - subtle but important when a "property" needs to be a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that in Javascript, functions are "first-class", meaning that a function can be treated exactly as you would treat any other variable: you can pass it to another function as a variable, and return it from another function.

This is heavily used in javascript, especially as callbacks.

When you call the `$.ajax` function, you provide it an object as an argument. This object will contain the callback functions for different states of the ajax request -- one of which is `success`.

So, basically, the key `success` needs to have a value of type function.

Now, when you say `displayResults("response")`, you are calling the function `displayResults` with an argument `"response"` -- the return type of which is  not a `function`.

If you just say `displayResults` without the `()`, you are treating the function exactly as you would do any other variable. The function is not executed.

You can do stuff like:

```
var functionAlias = displayResults;
```

Just like any other variable.

In the same way, you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: wikiAPI,
    dataType: "json",
    success: displayResults
});
```

Now, jquery will call the function you have provided when the ajax request has succeeded.

You can read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for what arguments to expect in the function:

> success
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR
>   )
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

So, your `displayResults` function will receive three arguments: `data` (can be of any type), `textStatus` (string), and `jqXHR` (XMLHttpRequest object). Although the argument names can be anything you want, it is common practice to keep it consistent with the docs.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

about the success method parameter, it has no specific name it's dynamic take a look at this link [JavaScript Object Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp)

about your code,make your ajax call like below

```
$.ajax({
url: wikiAPI,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){
displayResults(data)
},
error:function(erData):function{cosole.log(erData)}
});
```

It seems`displayResults` method is not complete since it receive an object as input you should iterate through your object in your method like below

```
function displayResults(data){
console.log("Ajax success response data:", data);
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
$(".results").append(data.YourProperty);
}) 
};
```

do note that I used `error` method to make sure ajax call succeeded if not the `error` method will be fired

Hope it hepls

Comment: Definitely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @garroad_ran happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$.ajax({
      url : wikiAPI,
      dataType : "json",
      success: function(response){
            displayResults(response)
         }
      });
})

function displayResults(data){
  console.log("Ajax success response data:", data); 
  $(".results").html("<p><h3>Hello World!</h3></p>");
}
```

Comment: or simply `success: displayResults`

Comment: This does not display "Hello World" on the page, nor does it write anything to the console. It almost seems like the request is not succeeding, but if that were the case then why would my original code succeed in printing "Hello World?"

Comment: So even though I called the function under the "success:" parameter, it would still fire even if the request failed?

Comment: you don't need to call your function at all. you need to pass it to the `$.ajax()` function as the parameter `success`. instead, you are passing void since your function returns nothing. is like { success: displayResults }. the ajax function will call the function when a response is ready from the server, since its an asynchronous action.

Comment: Ok, that is starting to make a lot more sense now. Thanks! Unfortunately, now I still have to get the code working, because your fixes haven't quite done so.